# QT для новичков

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие книги начать читать новичку по QT. Опыт программирования на С++ есть, но сам не могу перейти к QT...

Answer (score 5):

[Шлее](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4777403/) и [Бланшетт/Саммерфилд](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4005805/)

**UPD.** G71, [вот](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/index.html) еще ссылка на официальные доки, там слева в меню туторы и примеры есть.

Comment: я вот сейчас читаю Шлее, книжка неплохая для новичка, но сливком уже поверхностная, порой бывают темы, поглубже раскрываемые, но в основном всё наверху, с другой стороны, Qt слишком большой фрейворк...

Answer (score 1):

Ю.В.Земсков "Программирование на C++ с использованием библиотеки Qt4"

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/company/Nokia/blog/132006/) можно посмотреть тренинг для начинающих, если есть время.