# Среда разработки для C++

Tags: c++

Какой софт нужен чтобы программировать в C++?

Я новичок, есть опыт в PHP.

Comment: определитесь с платформой, а там уже ясно будет, советую также задать себе вопрос, что вы хотите получить от изучения языка.

Comment: хочу научиться писать программы для windows, есть планы и задумки ))

Comment: Они совсем не родственные. Только синтаксис похожий.

Answer (score 5):

**[Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP)** - возможный выбор для начала программирования под Windows, express версия полностью бесплатная.

p.s. советую так же обратить внимание на C#, как для начинающего этот язык намного проще в освоении, тем более переход с php будет намного плавнее, благодаря тому, что не придется разбираться в контроле памяти. Писать можно в все той же VS Express.

Comment: <b>+1</b> к "Visual Studio 2010 лучшая среда разработки для Windows".<br/>
<b>+1</b> к "С+  - разбираться в контроле памяти".<br/>
Но Вы так пишите как будто поработав в C# автор все же захочет потом писать на С++. Лично Я преимуществ С++ над C# не вижу, кроме как быстродействия.

Comment: От задачи зависит, для формочек шарп, для игр плюсы.

Comment: @ArtFeel, -1 к контролю памяти. Как для начинающего нужно научиться управлять памятью, чтбы потом не плеваться от языков без GC ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Так как платформа не указана:

- среда разработки [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), сборка "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers"
- Компиляторы gcc под линукс и mingw под винду.

Все линки гуглятся по именам продуктов.

Comment: я на windows 7 на данный момент, благодарю за ответ, пойду читать мануалы ))

Answer (score 2):

[Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads). Хотя по ссылке не только IDE, а SDK в целом. Ну и собственно [парочка учебников](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11605/qt-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 1):

Когда изучаете языки программирования. Рекомендую ВСЕ писать своими руками без фичи code-completion и без каких-либо отладчиков! Лучший Ваш отладчик это Ваши руки и голова. Руки должны запомнить как писать правильно синтаксически. А голова должна запоминать идиомы и подходы используемые в языке.

Пишите в Notepad++ или Sublime Text.

Перед компиляцией оглянитесь и посмотрите на свой код. Спросите себя "Он точно скомпилируется?" и только потом компилируйте. Так Вы лучше усвоите язык.

Среды разработки упрощают жизнь тех, кто переходит на решение "боевых" задач.