# C++ или Delphi?

Tags: delphi, c++

Хочу поинтересоваться, если делать приложение полностью создавая с нуля интерфейс, использую только стандартные Parent-ы то в какой среде это получится сделать более качественно?

Comment: Стандартные паренты - имеется в виду без использования доп. библиотек? Т.е. голый WinAPI? Ну, это застрелиться в голову. Вероятнее всего проще всего будет использовать С++, т.к. примеров использования существенно больше.

Comment: Вообще вопрос задан некорректно. Правильно так C++ или Pascal либо Visual C++ или Delphi.

Answer (score 4):

**С Delphi не знаком!**

У использования плюсов есть некоторые плюсы :)

Во-первых, зная C++ есть возможность использовать бОльшее количество различных библиотек, будь то GUI, мультитридинг или сетевая разработка. К тому же (на мой взгляд) у C++ больше "комьюнити" и больший потенциал чем у дельфей.

Во-вторых. Касательно гуев и плюсов: [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11605/qt-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) есть названия книг по [Qt](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt). Я уверен что разработанное на нем ПО будет более качественным, чем на Delphi, и даже чистом WinAPI. К тому же приложения созданные с использованием C++/Qt можно перекомпилировать и они <s>без проблем</s> будут работать как на MacOSX, так и на Linux.

Comment: Ну, у дельфи был один серьезный козырь. Под названием Kylix. Но он почил в бозе =( Есть еще Lazarus, с которым есть ограниченная совместимость. 

С другой стороны, язык ObjectPascal, используемый в Delphi, немного более щадящ по отношению к не "про"-программерах. Потому что в "настоящем" С++ много подводных камней. Хотя я бы тоже писал именно на C++/Qt.

Comment: Дельфи, похоже, завел новый козырь. В свежей версии XE2, судя по всему, предлагается разработка под Windows и OS X.

Comment: После пары лет на дельфях в С++ я увидел не подводные камни, а три вагона западла, как будто его туда специально пихали всем комьюнити. Пишешь себе кусок кода по книжке, а он платформ-специфик, хочет три библиотеки (узнать их можно только по неопределенным переменным), которые раскиданы по всему миру и одна из них несовместима по версиям, а другая с каментами на испанском. Its great fun. Причем тут нужен не профессионализм, а большое желания секса хоть где-то. Мне его хватает, поэтому не понравилось)) В общем, я за делфи, если не нужны "новейшие разработки". Все имхо, не хотел никого обидеть.

Answer (score 2):

Не  соглашусь.

Все зависит от количества серого вещества того кто делает.

и опять будет холивар что круче C++ или Delphi

Answer (score 2):

Подытожив и выразив свое мнение:

С++:

1. Можно использовать мощнейшие (к тому
       же кроссплатформенные)тулкиты:
       Qt!!!, GTK+, xwWidgets и если
       покопать то еще много чего.
2. Врожденная кросплотформенность - перенос на другую платформу и
       написание изначально
       кроссплатформенного кода
       относительно безболезненны и явно
       возможны.
3. Быстродействие - на порядок выше быстродействия приложений на Delphi
       и многих других языках.
4. Размер компилированного кода минимален.

Delphi:

1. Быстрая разработка. Идеально для
       простых "офисных" приложений.
2. Довольно простая отладка.
3. ГОРАЗДО меньше возможности по неопытности накосячить в коде.
4. БОЛЬШОЙ объем компилированного кода.
5. Полное отсутствие кросплатформенности.

Comment: Delphi: размер проги на "голом винапи" очень слабо отличается от размера проги на с++ с qt. Про кроссплатформенность писали выше, да и обычно дельфисты не ориентированы на линух(ибо аллергия как у линуксоидов на винду). Если сделают адекватную платформу для макоси - можно считать, что началась holy war в прямом смысле - с++/никс/опенсорс vs delphi/win/корпорации. Cyberpunk is now ^^

Comment: Про винапи полностью соглашусь. Но, по моему, на Делфи редко кто идет в такие дебри. Многие используют Делфи как раз как RAD-среду разработки. Натыкал быстро мышкой, написал предельно понятный (фиг допустишь ошибок) код - и все работает. А о размере в таких случаях мало думают. А по поводу ExePack, если я не ошибаюсь, он никак не уменьшает объем компилированного кода, а лишь упаковывает Exe-шник. При его запуске происходит распаковка до прежнего объема. Я прав? Но, на самом деле, это опять же минусы, которые никому не мешают.

Comment: > редко кто идет в такие дебри

Вот именно в этом главная проблема, а не в среде/языке. Я только контролы мышкой добавляю (не всегда), остальное ручками-ручками, + ассемблер, + оптимизация раза 3 и т.д. Про упаковщики - ээм, да, тут уже мой фейл, не вникал. Спасибо за инфу, кстати) Больше, видимо, пользовать не буду.

Answer (score 2):

Дельфисты и сиплюсисты вечно в противостоянии, этот вопрос терзал многих. Одни обливают грязью и скудностью обьектный паскаль и производные продукты (делфи, BDS Delphi), другие говорят напротив, что с++ (Visual) сложен для построения информационных систем, так как работа с БД Borland отточила на максимум. Баталии споров помню еще между pascalщиками и сиплюсплюсчиками. Если ум, есть, то можно в любом инструментарии создать продукт-конфетку, на которую будет любо, дорого смотреть. Вообще я знаю и делфи и с++, для меня они практически равноценны. Будущее за c#, если говорить о прикладном программирование. Если говорить о сетях и интернете, то пора ударяться в облачные технологии, через 4-6 лет они заполонят нас). Идеология ООП одинакова в общем случае у них, но за с++ больше практического кода, и как правильно сказали люди большая часть библиотек писалось на нем. Быстрее наверное на с++, хотя я бы эскпериментировал и там, и там).

Answer (score 0):

> делать приложение полностью создавая с нуля интерфейс

Имеете в виду на голом WinAPI? Тогда, пожалуй, лучше с++.