# C++ библиотека QT (Creator)

Tags: qt, c++, creator

Здравствуйте я не так давно проявил интерес к библиотеке QT. 
Не могли бы вы дать мне мануал по использованию визуальных средств (В QT Creator)?
К примеру как составить элементарную программу с просмотром достоинств QT?

Answer (score 3):

Вам будет очень интересна эта книга [Макс Шлее - Qt4.5. Профессиональное программирование на C++](http://c2p.ru/cpp/maks-shlee-qt4-5-professionalnoe-programmirovanie-na-c.html)

Comment: Да я вот как раз купил эту книгу спасибо за совет =)

Answer (score 3):

[QT для новичков.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11605/qt-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Пользуйтесь поиском по форуму!

Answer (score 2):

я вот сам сейчас занимаюсь изучением Qt. Лучше начните без Qt Designer. Просто в ручную посоздавайте простенькие GUI-приложения, а потом уже с помощью визуальных редакторов. Если зайти в Google, перейти в раздел видео и набрать там Qt. Будет много видео по созданию приложений на Qt - как раз с помощью редактора. Можно там поглядеть.

Comment: Тоже спасибо за совет! Идея интересная.  Жаль не могу +к рейтингу дать. Репутации не хватает(